# Attach a node to a menu link OR attach custom fields to menu links?

Tags: 7, entities, routes, nodes, navigation

My client would like to add content to the top-level links in the main menu, in order to have "Featured" content that is displayed in the drop-down menu. They must be able to choose which piece of content will be shown, and which menu link it will be associated with. I figure I have two options:

1) Creating a "Featured in Menu" Content Type and adding a drop-down menu of top-level menu links as a field. The problem with this is I am not sure how to output a custom field that will list top-level main menu links. There does not seem to be a module currently that will achieve this, so I guess I would have to do it from scratch.

2) Adding custom fields to the main menu links themselves (image, title, node reference). I tried using the [Power Menu module](http://drupal.org/project/power_menu) to achieve this, however every version of the module I tried gave SQL errors and broke the Edit Menu page. I'm hesitant to debug and pursue a fix for that module if it could end up being unstable.

I'm not sure which solution would be preferable but either way I'm stuck! I would very much appreciate some help on how to achieve either one of these solutions. (Or if I'm totally over-thinking this and there's a much easier way to achieve this, by all means please let me know.) For the record, I'm using Drupal 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into like [Menu Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_views) or GigaMenu or MegaMenu ... there are a few solutions that let you place a view in a menu.

Then you can either add a field to a content type such as, "include in featured menu" of type boolean, that you use as a Filter in your View. Or, re-use the "promote to frontpage" re-labeled to fit your needs on a specific content type.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts tenken. I have been looking into Menu Views and have it saved just in case I end up using my first method of a custom content type. However, my issue is that the client will want to choose a specific menu link for each 'Featured Content' node, so a checkbox alone won't work. I also will need a drop-down menu (or similar) of top-level parent links, which is where I get stuck.

I wonder if I can maybe incorporate the default "Menu Settings" to choose the menu link ... but I'm not sure how to restrict that drop-down to just top-level links.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used and like [Menu Attach Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block)

> Menu Attach Block allows you to attach blocks to standard core Drupal
>   menu items. This is especially useful for creating complex dropdown
>   menus and mega menus.
>
> Any block can be used, including blocks generated by other modules.
>   Blocks generated by Views are particularly good candidates for
>   embedding.
>
> You can choose to replace menu items with Blocks, or keep the menu
>   items and have the block available by clicking a link which is
>   inserted beside the menu item.
>
> You can see this module in use at Syfy.de (click the drop-down arrows
>   in the main menu).